# Sed (POSIX) coming from linux

Tags: sed, posix

I am somewhat new to posix, and i can't use: `sed '1~2p'`

My goal is to skip every one line from line 1:

```
1
2
3
4
```

would become

```
1
3
```

I was wondering what is the posix equivalent of `~`.

Comment: What is the reason behind `and i can't use: sed '1~2p'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -e n -e d file
```

or:

```
sed -e 'n;d' file
```

Comment: You'll need to quote the sed program for the 2nd example.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler, portable solution would be:

```
awk 'NR%2' file
```

Answer (score 1):

`bash` solution:

```
while read -r line; do 
  [ $((i++ % 2)) -eq 0 ] && echo "$line"; 
done < file
```